# How to keep backup of Android Keystore's master key or create from user input?

Tags: java, android, android-keystore, tink

I am using Google/Tink's Deterministic symmetric key encryption in my project. Like this-

```
byte[] ciphertext;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String plainText="Hello World";
try {
            DeterministicAeadConfig.register();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
try {
                    KeysetHandle keysetHandle = KeysetHandle.generateNew(
                            KeyTemplates.get("AES256_SIV"));
                    Log.d("TAG",keysetHandle.toString());
                    DeterministicAead daead =
                            keysetHandle.getPrimitive(DeterministicAead.class);
                    ciphertext = daead.encryptDeterministically(plainText.getBytes(),null);
                    String c= new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext));
                    Log.d("TAG",c);

                    MasterKey mainKey = new MasterKey.Builder(context)
                            .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
                            .build();
                    Log.d("TAG",mainKey.toString());

                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/my_keyset.json";
                    String masterKeyUri = "android-keystore://_androidx_security_master_key_";
                    keysetHandle.write(JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File(filePath)),
                            new AndroidKeystoreKmsClient().getAead(masterKeyUri));

                } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Everything is okay. Now which master key I am creating for Android keyStore, can be deleted/lost if the user reset the phone or any other accident occur (other reasons). Then Tink's keyset(key) will be un-usable. **Is there any way to keep backup of master key or create the master key from user input or any other solution?**

Note: AWS KMS or GCP KMS isn't a solution for me. As a newcomer in cryptography, any suggestion/advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My first Tink library encounter was using my app to decode a protected SNMP SMI tree (our ciphertext) of our JV partner's IP before it could be utilized for SNMP OID operations. I discovered that I needed to keep the same master key for the same ciphertext.

As a result, executing the `KeysetHandle.generateNew()` method every time my app opens is no longer an option because it generates a new master key that no longer works with the existing ciphertext stored in the app private folder.

I discovered that the Tink library allows us to save the master key in a keyset file format of our choice, which we can then utilize in our app to reload the same master key for the app's keyset handle.

```java
    String keysetFileName =
        StorageUtils.getPrivateKeyPath()
            + File.separator + "smi.json";

    //write it as a file
    CleartextKeysetHandle
        .write(keysetHandle, JsonKeysetWriter.withFile(new File(keysetFileName)));
```

To reload it into the keyset handle, we use this code:

```java
    String keysetFileName =
        StorageUtils.getPrivateKeyPath()
            + File.separator + "smi.json";

    //read it as a file
    keysetHandle =
        CleartextKeysetHandle.read(JsonKeysetReader.withFile(new File(keysetFileName)));
```

Please keep in mind that I do not actually store the keyset file in the device storage. I use the `build.gradle` script to copy the keyset file's content into the app's **EncryptedSharedPreferences** object and retrieve it as a string as shown below:

```java
    // onCreate()
    securedSharedPreferences = 
        StorageUtils.getEncryptedSharedPreferences(context);

    securedSharedPreferences.edit()
            .putString("key", BuildConfig.SECRET_KEY).apply();

    // somewhere else when we need it...

    String keysetFileName =
        securedSharedPreferences.getString("key", null);

    //read it as a string
    keysetHandle =
        CleartextKeysetHandle.read(JsonKeysetReader.withString(keysetFileName));
```

The above approach is still insecure because we may expose `BuildConfig.SECRET KEY` in our code. The ideal method to handle this problem is to ask our user to load the keyset file and save it in the safe **EncryptedSharedPreferences** object.